# Delete the rows that have the same value in the columns Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this :

| origin | destination |
| --- | --- |
| germany | germany |
| germany | italy |
| germany | spain |
| USA | USA |
| USA | spain |
| Argentina | Argentina |
| Argentina | Brazil |

and I want to filter the routes that are within the same country, that is, I want to obtain the following dataframe :

| origin | destination |
| --- | --- |
| germany | italy |
| germany | spain |
| USA | spain |
| Argentina | Brazil |

How can i do this with pandas ?  I have tried deleting duplicates but it does not give me the results I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple filter:

```
df = df[df['origin'] != df['destination']]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      origin destination
1    germany       italy
2    germany       spain
4        USA       spain
6  Argentina      Brazil
```

Answer (score 0):

We could `query`:

```
out = df.query('origin!=destination')
```

Output:

```
      origin destination
1    germany       italy
2    germany       spain
4        USA       spain
6  Argentina      Brazil
```